# Lead Report with Account object

Tags: custom-report-type

I have a custom lookup field created in Lead object lookup on Account.

Now I want to create a report where I want to get all lead fields but also a field from account object other than account id.

I have tried creating a report type but cannot see Account object as B (Detail side). Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a visualforce page or you can download both reports and do it in .xls use lookup. Or you can run custom code on the anonymous window to generate CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in my development org and I am able to do it from the other way.

1. Create lookup field on the lead to the account.
2. Create new report type for Accounts & Contacts.
3. For the B object, select the Lead object.
4. Select "Each "A" record must have at least one related "B" record." for the relationship. Then only accounts that are related to at least one lead will be included in the report.